# How to use Parse.Op in cloud code?

Tags: parse-platform, parse-cloud-code, parse-server

I would like to know in cloud code if the request is adding or removing an item from a ParseRelation. How to get information from the Parse Operation.
For now I cannot get any information from Parse.Op.

for i.e : in a beforeSave() method  :

```
var parseOp = myObject.op('myRelation');
if (parseOp != null) {
    console.log("Operations on myRelation  = " + parseOp.toJSON() );
}
```

in log this display only :  `Operations on myRelation = [object Object]`

There is no information in Parse SDK js documentation. on how to use ParseOp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the issue here regarding this:
https://github.com/ParsePlatform/Parse-SDK-JS/issues/133

If you still want to use `.op` you can try something like this:

```
var parseOp = myObject.op('myRelation');
if (parseOp) {
    console.log('array of objectIds to add', parseOp.relationsToAdd)
    console.log('array of objectIds to remove', parseOp.relationsToRemove)
    // do more things here
}
```

*Note: you can pass multiple arguments to `console.log(...)` and objects will be printed out*

Comment: Thanks, I will check this. Since we should avoid to use Parse.Op directly (according to your link), do you have an idea on How to increment a counter when an object is added (or removed) from a ParseRelation ?

Comment: You can increment the counter wherever you're adding to the relation. Or you can run a `find` on the relation and get the length of the results.

Comment: The increment must be from server side for data integrity: for i.e.: when a user like a Post he add it to his ParseRelation "liked". But the number of Likes for this post can't be incremented by the user himself (to avoid cheating). I can't query a find and count all the time as well (a post may be liked by more than 10000 users).

Comment: @toofoo Based on that I would recommend using the `parseOp` code I posted in the answer. In the future, just be mindful whenever upgrading to a new version of Parse Server (ideally with some unit tests).